# SQL Server Export to flat file has unexpected row breaks

Tags: sql, sql-server, export, export-to-csv

I have an interesting issue. I have a table that has 300,000 rows records in it. When I export to a flat file, regardless of delimiter, it does indeed say it's exporting 300,000 rows. However when I open in a text editor or try to re-import that flat file into another SQL Server table.. it added rows... like 50k worth.

Upon reviewing the flatfile in a text editor like Pilot Edit, I see the rows are not consistent. There is a weird row break that's happening.. and thus when I import into another servers table, it imports a broken file... with 50k extra rows.

Whats going wrong with the export?? How can I make it simply export exactly what is in the tables.. data that's all nice and clean ?

Also it should be noted I have the row delimiter set to `{CR}{LF}` and also set it to a pipe just to try.. same results...

Comment: How exactly are you doing the export?

Comment: and if you try to map the first extra row break with the corresponding row/column content of your table, what do you find? any fancy character? a blob field?

Comment: @KenClement well the same way I have been for years. Select the source, set a destination as flat file, choose the table and literally select every column, change the delimiter to pipe and export..

Comment: @PhilippeGrondier it does seem there is a consistant coulmn it break on... the same one throughout. The best way to describe it by looking at the file is as if you hit the return key in the text editor and it shifted the remaining column down to the next row...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it. had a hidden carriage return in a column

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(COLUMN NAME, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')))
```